# How to add label to numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I just trying to add label to numpy.ndarray.

```
numpy.ndarray's shape is (?, 1, 100, 100)

[[[ 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
          ...
  [ 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]]
```

and label is `[1,0]` or `[0,1]`

so i want shape like this

```
[[[ 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
          ...
  [ 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]] , [1,0]
```

or

```
[[[ 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
          ...
  [ 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]] , [0,1]
```

how to make this shape???

I tried like this but doesn't work.

```py
data_train = []
for i in range(len(true_data.tolist())):
    true_data[i].append([1,0])
    data_train.append(true_data[i])
```

Comment: I suppose you're training a classifier. Why don't you simply use two different arrays for your inputs and your labels? This is the way to do it with usual machine learning libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer by myself!

this is my code

```py
data_train = []
true_list = true_data.tolist()
for index in range(len(true_list)):
    true_list[index].append([1,0])
    temp = np.asarray(true_list[index])
    data_train.append(temp)
```